# Knowing which animated object is touched in the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I implemented a code to touch and drag an object between many animated objects in the view, and it works, now I need to know which object I touched in the view.

Comment: If you don't give us some of your code, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: [Matt Gemmel](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) could help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Each view has an `NSInteger` tag attribute, it can be set in the Interface Builder-like UI, or in code like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.tag = 20121221;
```

You can get the view associated with a tag through

```
[parentView viewWithTag:20121221];
```